# Good Scatter-plot plugin for JQuery (sample pic included)?

Tags: jquery, graph, plugins, scatter-plot

I'm looking for a solid graphing plugin for JQuery that can give me an attractive scatterplot for use on my site. I really don't need a lot of fancy functionality -- just the ability to plot points on a graph based on the X-axis and Y-axis values I give it.

The only somewhat peculiar requirement I have is that the dots have the ability to be different colors. In addition to tracking the item's "State" on the X-Axis, and it's "Input Time" on the Y-Axix, I want to represent it's "Status" (not to be confused with "State") by the actual color of the dot. Incidentally, there are 5 States, and 5 Statuses.

I found a couple of promising ones in a quick Google search, but didn't see the ability to specify the color of the dot (I found one that let me change the size, however). Any suggestions anyone has would be greatly appreciated.

Below is kind of what I'm going for, but I think the dots would be arranged more cleanly in 5 distinct columns (based on the 5 States). But it might help with visualization.

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FLOT](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) is a really nice charting plugin.  It doesn't specifically support scatter charts (to my knowledge) but it does support [point charts](http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/graph-types.html).  Check out the [usage page](http://code.google.com/p/flot/wiki/FlotUsage) for some examples on how it has been used to create scatters.

Comment: Thanks AJ, I had noticed this one in the past. I've started using it, but I've noticed a couple limitations. Hopefully I can work around them. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Personally I love this:

http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/

See if this is enough for You. It won't get easier and more comfortable.

[and it has lots of samples on main page :)]