# Distribution of data in the circle

Tags: php, web-applications, jquery-plugins

Lets say I have elements (`E1, E2, ... ,En`) that have individual values which varies in `[1;  100]`. I have a circle (*see figure below*) and each two circle represent range of data. 
The problem is how to show distribution of these elements of`E`in this circle. Figure below depicts distribution of some elements of`E`in the circle, where for example `E1=10, E2=35,...,E6=100, E7=91`. Are there any ready libraries in PHP or any plugins in jQuery or any ready solution?
I need to implement this problem in my **web application** using HTML+CSS+jQuery (don't offer solution with flash technologies, please).
**Note:** It is like creating charts in MS Excel. For example in MS Excel there is a chart type  called *Radar* which more or less implements this problem, but in my case I have circles instead of polygon and I have only limited range of `[1;100]`.

**Edit**
I have forgotten to mention that in this figure *object* element which is in the center is the object based on which we are showing distribution. If element matches *object* with more percentage so close it to the *object* and vice versa.
[image: Distribution of data in the circle]

Comment: Why did you tag this PHP? From your description, a server side solution doesn't seem acceptable.

Comment: I assumed PHP, because maybe I will create this figure in PHP with some ready libraries and send to the client an image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incomplete, see the [GD](http://php.net/gd) manual on how to add text, etc.

```
<?php
$size = 501; //odd

$img = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);

$center = array((int) ($size/2), (int) ($size/2));
$colors['white'] = imagecolorallocate($img, 255, 255, 255);
$colors['black'] = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
$colors['blue'] = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 255);

imagefill($img, 0, 0, $colors['white']);

$valid_rad = array((int) (($center[0] - 1) * .2), (int) (($center[0] - 1) * .9));

function radius_for($percentage, $valid_rad) {
    return $valid_rad[1] - ($valid_rad[1] - $valid_rad[0]) *
        ($percentage/100);
}

foreach (array(0,25,50,75,100) as $perc) {
    $radius = radius_for($perc, $valid_rad);
    imagearc($img, $center[0], $center[1], $radius*2, $radius*2,
        0, 360, $colors['black']);
}


foreach (array(100,85,70,36,23,2) as $perc) {
    $radius = radius_for($perc, $valid_rad);
    $angle = pi() * 1.25 + ((rand(0,100) - 50) / 50) * .5;
    $x = (int) ($radius * cos($angle)) + $center[0];
    $y = (int) ($radius * sin($angle)) + $center[1];

    imagefilledellipse($img, $x, $y , 20, 20, $colors['blue']);
}


header("Content-type: image/png");
imagepng($img);
```

This gives a picture like this:

[image: sample]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was very fast reply. Now I will try to do that with canvas in HTML5+CSS+jQuery. I think it is not so difficult. I will follow you algorithm.

Comment: The only problem it has is overlapping of elements, when rand(0,100) generates similar numbers.

Comment: @Bakhtiyor Well, you can generate `n` different random numbers (regenerate if you get a number seen before), change `((rand(0,100) - 50) / 50) * .5` to `((rand(0,20) - 10) / 10) * .5` so that the numbers are less similar or increase the multiplication factor `.5` so that the circles are more dispersed.

Comment: But anyway, I highly appreciate your help. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any pre-made graphs like that.  However you may be able to replicate it with a scatter plot with a custom background.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268675/good-scatter-plot-plugin-for-jquery-sample-pic-included) are some jquery ones.  You'd have to do the math to create the x,y coordinates with the appropriate distance from the center point but the chart plug-in should take care of the rest.